# How can I share share read/write access to a file within the same process, but forbid it externally?

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi, file-permissions

I have a few objects that hold a handle to the same file. However, each of these objects is reading/writing a different part the file. I need to prevent external access to the file, but still be able to create new handles to it from within my process.

If I don't share read/write access when invoking `CreateFile`, I can't obtain new handles to the file from within my process. If I use `DuplicateHandle`, all of the handles will share the same file position.

I can work around this by making a proxy to the file that seeks all over the place as needed, but this makes for terrible design. Is there any way to accomplish internal sharing like this?

Comment: I personally would go down the "one handle, seek" route. Possibly with some buffering/caching functionality.

Comment: Can the "prevent external access" part be by convention?  For example, can you create some kind of "semaphore" (e.g., something as simple as another file sitting on disk) that indicates the file is in use and that other processes cannot access the file?  Maybe to put it more simply, do you have control over all processes involved?

Comment: I have no control or idea of the external process(es).

Comment: it maybe interesting for your case. Look at overlapped access http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686358%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you might be able to call `CreateFile()` once to create/open the file, and then have each of your objects use `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` to access different sections of the file using that single file handle as the base.

Answer (score 1):

Files are generally not for multi-user interactions such as this.  A database is what is needed here.  Then the data you need written can be saved to the database and all the synchronous handling would now be the databases responsibility.  If you still require a file, after the data has been input, it would be an idea to generate the file when needed based off the database data.